# Python importing item.py file in scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have the following folder structure

```
/project
   /scrape
        item.py
        /spiders
               myscraper.py
```

inside the file item.py i have a declaration for

```
class MyItem(Item):
```

with a lot more code in it.

I am trying to run scrapy as

scrapy crawl myscraper

from the folder /project, but I keep getting the error.

```
 exceptions.NameError: global name 'MyItem' is not defined
```

Would anyone know what I need to do different to make sure scrapy sees my item.py file?
Thanks

Comment: We need to see much more of your code to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't be sure because I can see so few of your code, but it looks like you have a circular import.

Check if you are not importing something from one file and vice-versa, rearrange your code so that it doesn't happen anymore.